# How to add Listview to publishing page through CAML provisioning

Tags: sharepoint, provisioning, caml

it is a big question since long time and now I am facing it.... 
I have to add list view web part through CAML to publish page.
I have used the code:

```
<View List="0GeneralInformationandReports" RowLimit="5" FreeForm="TRUE" 
  BaseViewID="0"
  RecurrenceRowset="TRUE"
  WebPartZoneID="bottomLeft_LeftZone"
  WebPartOrder="1">
    <![CDATA[
         <webParts>
              <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                  <metaData>
                      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                  </metaData>
                  <data>
                      <properties>
                          <property name="Title">0 - General Information and Reports</property>
                          <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
                          <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">False</property>
                          <property name="Height" type="unit">215px</property>
                      </properties>
                  </data>
              </webPart>
          </webParts>          
    ]]>
  </View>
```

and it is rendering fine with the list view on the page. But i have to add more control to the web part like show only limited columns and top 5 modified by date ascending. This is not working using the  tag as there are no other ways I can add sorting, view fields etc...
please help.

---

I have tried that and still it is not working. This is my list view in schema.xml.

```
<View DisplayName="" BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Hidden="TRUE" XslLink="main.xsl"
        WebPartZoneID="bottomLeft_LeftZone" WebPartOrder="0">
    <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
    <Query />
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="DocIcon" />
      <FieldRef Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu" />
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit>5</RowLimit>
    <Aggregations Value="Off" />
  </View>
    </Views>
```

Still it is showing the same fields... No ideas how to get to it... I have referenced BaseView="0" in the  of my elements.xml. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you'll probably have to define a new View in your List Definition, and then use BaseViewID to specify the new view by that ID.